# Guide on Using Speech Recognizer

Tags: android, accessibility, speech-recognition

I am using the following guide "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AnNJPf-4T70&index=13&t=0s&list=LLWs2Xlax6q42i66xW1W7F3Q" to try and develop a demo app so That I can become familiar with using speech recognizer in an actual app and learn how to develop an app that can be controlled via voice to allow individuals with motor impairments to use all my apps I build in the future.

I have an interest in using intents to use the test app such as opening a browser just as a sample but I have matched the code and have run into an error I can't find a solution to.

Here  is my activity xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Blind Accessibility Demo"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_mic_black_24dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp" />


</RelativeLayout>

Below is my Main activity class

package com.example.ricardo.voicecontrol;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognitionListener;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.speech.SpeechRecognizer;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //    this initalizes the text to speech variable
    private TextToSpeech myTTS;
    //this initalizes the speech reconizer variable
    private SpeechRecognizer speechtest;
private  FloatingActionButton fab;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
               intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                       RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
               intent.putExtra((RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS),1);
               speechtest.startListening(intent);


            }
        });
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


//this initalizes text to speech
        initializeTextToSpeech();

//        this code initalizses or "starts" the speech recognizer
        initializeSpeechRecognizer();

    }


    private void initializeSpeechRecognizer() {
        if (SpeechRecognizer.isRecognitionAvailable((this))
                ) {
            speechtest = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
            speechtest.setRecognitionListener(new RecognitionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onEndOfSpeech() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(int error) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onResults(Bundle bundle) {
                    List<String> results = bundle.getStringArrayList(
                            (
                                    SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION
                            ));
                    processResults(results.get(0));

                }

                @Override
                public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {

                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void processResults(String command) {
        command = command.toLowerCase();
        if (command.indexOf("open") != -1) {
            if (command.indexOf("browser") != -1) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.yahoo.com/"));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }

}
//        what is your name
//    what is the time





    private void initializeTextToSpeech() {
        myTTS = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if (myTTS.getEngines().size() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There is no text to speech engine available on your phone"
                            , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                } else {
                    myTTS.setLanguage(Locale.US);
//                    this line of code below will be spoken once the app loads up
                    speak("This app can be controlled using your voice tap the microphone icon to begin");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void speak(String message) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            myTTS.speak(message, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
        } else {
            myTTS.speak(message, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }

        }
    @Override
    protected void onPause () {
        super.onPause();
        myTTS.shutdown();
    }

    private class FloatingActionButton {
        public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener onClickListener) {
        }
    }
}
```

The error I am getting is         "Inconvertible types; cannot cast to  'android.viewView to 'com.example.ricardo.voicecontrol.MainActivity.FloatingActionButton'' " 
I have tried renaming the file and invalidating cash and restarting but found no change.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your FloatingActionButton is not a View you create an inner class

```
private class FloatingActionButton {
    public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener onClickListener) {
    }
}
```

That should not be there at all. You created a class that does not extend View and tried to use it as a View. Take this class out and use a FloatingActionButton from a library. This is the root cause of your error.

Try changing

```
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
           intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                   RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
           intent.putExtra((RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS),1);
           speechtest.startListening(intent);


        }
    });
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

To

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
           intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                   RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
           intent.putExtra((RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS),1);
           speechtest.startListening(intent);


        }
    });
```

I would expect you to be getting a NullPointerException.

This line of code

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Is saying; load my xml file activity_main as the current layout for this activity.

And this line of code

```
 FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
```

Is saying; In the xml file that I loaded with setContentView find a view with the ID fab and cast that to a FloatingActionButton

So they way your code is laid out, you try and find the view before it been loaded.

Comment: I totally missed that slip up, I have corrected it based on your guidance however the original error  of ""Inconvertible types; cannot cast to 'android.viewView to 'com.example.ricardo.voicecontrol.MainActivity.FloatingActionButton'' remains. despite the corrected code.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you, the error went away. However I am not able to get the intent to work on opening the browser even though the "record audio" and "internet" permissions are recorded in the android manifest file. I will look more into the structure of my code to try and fix this issue.